# PHP if before <html> tag giving error 500

Tags: php, html, if-statement, tags

I'm trying to do something that when you open something like index.php?bodyonly=1 php only returns what's inside the body html tag. However when I try something like the following code:

```
<?php if !isset($_GET["bodyonly"]): ?><html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Up!</p>

        <?php endif; ?><p>Down!</p><?php if !isset($_GET["bodyonly"]): ?>
    </body>
</html><?php endif; ?>
```

I get an error 500 and nothing happens. If I try an alternative using if(isset...){ echo ... } stuff happens like it should, but then I have to do a lot of other changes that I don't want to.

Care to enlighten me? :)

Comment: what's this?? `if !isset($_GET["bodyonly"]):`

Comment: Is not having your `if` condition inside parentheses a typo? It's required even for the alternative syntax AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

In all types of PHP syntax, conditions need brackets about them.

```
<?php if (!isset($_GET["bodyonly"])): ?><html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Up!</p>

        <?php endif; ?><p>Down!</p><?php if (!isset($_GET["bodyonly"])): ?>
    </body>
</html><?php endif; ?>
```

Also, have you considered using more modern structure for your code?  Curly braces and use of PHP as a programming language rather than an HTML wrapper make it very easy to see what's being run conditionally.

```
<?php

$status="Up";
// $status="Down";

$header="<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>TEST</title>\n\t</head>\n\n  <body>\n";
$footer="  </body>\n</html>\n";

if (!isset($_GET["bodyonly"])) {
  print $header;
}

printf("\t<p>%s</p>\n", $status);

if (!isset($_GET["bodyonly"])) {
  print $footer;
}
```

Or, for the fun of it, even:

```
<?php

$status="Up";
// $status="Down";

$header="<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>TEST</title>\n\t</head>\n\n  <body>\n";
$footer="  </body>\n</html>\n";

print isset($_GET["bodyonly"]) ? "" : $header;

printf("\t<p>%s</p>\n", $status);

print isset($_GET["bodyonly"]) ? "" : $footer;
```

Or (and this is just getting silly):

```
<?php

$status="Up";
// $status="Down";

$header=""; $footer="";

if (!isset($_GET["bodyonly"])) {
  $header="<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>TEST</title>\n\t</head>\n\n  <body>\n";
  $footer="  </body>\n</html>\n";
}

print $header . sprintf("\t<p>%s</p>\n", $status) . $footer;
```

Have a look at the [instructions on syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php) from php.net.